# python cx_Freeze egg problem

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

im trying to build an executable (for 32bit windows xp) from a python script (which uses lots of eggs)

i considered py2exe(0.6.9), PyInstaller (1.4) and cx_Freeze (4.1.2)

[py2exe doesnt like eggs for breakfast](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs)

[PyInstaller doesnt like python 2.6 for lunch](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/Python26Win))

so i went with cx_Freeze ([supposed to support eggs seamlessly since 4.0](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/HISTORY.txt)). but for some reason it doesnt.

what parameters do i pass in order for files inside an egg to be recognized?

Answer (score 3):

Unpack your eggs module in your source directory and add `package: [dependencies,]` in your setup.py.
Following the py2exe docs in [py2Exe Docs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs) i did this script that you most run in your source executing: `python unpackEgg.py eggsmodule`:

```
    import os
    import pkg_resources
    import sys
    from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive

    def unpackEgg(modulo):
        eggs = pkg_resources.require(modulo)
        for egg in eggs:
            if os.path.isdir(egg.location):
                sys.path.insert(0, egg.location)
                continue
            unpack_archive(egg.location, ".")
        eggpacks = set()
        eggspth = open("./eggs.pth", "w")
        for egg in eggs:
            print egg
            eggspth.write(os.path.basename(egg.location))
            eggspth.write("\n")
            eggpacks.update(egg.get_metadata_lines("top_level.txt"))
        eggspth.close()

        eggpacks.clear()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
    unpackEgg(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Brillient! this works with cx freeze and python 3.3 too, just change print egg to print(egg)

Answer (score 0):

You could try PyInstaller's 2.6 branch that is linked in the page you gave.