# Packaging using py2exe with extra modules

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to create an .exe file from a python script using py2exe. Whenever I try running the program, it seems that it is missing a module (pyping).

I have tried:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=[{"script": "main.py"}], 
      options={"py2exe": {"includes": ["pyping"]}})
```

and:

```
python setup.py py2exe --includes pyping
```

But py2exe always returns "No module named pyping"?

Comment: Do you have `pyping` installed?

Comment: Yes I do if I run the same script with python _nameofthescript_ it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zip2exe [FAQ](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/GeneralTipsAndTricks) has a section about dealing with ["No module named ..."](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/DealingWithImportError) which links you to [exe with eggs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs) which suggests the issue is that `pyping` is installed as an egg instead of unzipped. The first solution is to manually install it unzipped with `easy_install --always-unzip`. The second is to include the actual package in your source folder.

Here is another question discussing other alternatives like [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/):

[python cx_Freeze egg problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633655/python-cx-freeze-egg-problem)